# Chain Dependant Observables in Resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a resolver that needs to fetch data from two dependant Apis before the page is loaded. The second call is defined by the result of the first one, so I try to chain the two observables and need to return the second one at the end of the resolver.

Before I tried to chain the observables I had:

```js
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<MySecondObservable> {
        
        const observable1 = this.myService.getFirstDataSet();
        observable1.subscribe(
             firstDataSet => this.myService.firstDataSet = firstDataSet;
        );
    
        const observable2 = this.myService.getSecondDataSet(); // this requires data from firstDataSet
        observable2.subscribe(
             secondDataSet => this.myService.secondDataSet = secondDataSet;
        );

        return observable2;
    }
```

This is obvioulsy wrong, when I try to apply some RxJs methods to pipe these observables I get an error in the second observable call saying that the firstDataSet is not defined.
Here is what I got so far:

```js
    return observable1.pipe(
        tap( firstDataSet => this.myService.firstDataSet = firstDataSet),
        mergeMap( () => observable2.pipe(
            tap(secondDataSet => this.myService.secondDataSet = secondDataSet            
            ) 
        )
    )
```

At each observable final result I want to store the received data into the service hence the `tap()`. There is an overwhelming amount of documentation on RxJS, at the point that I found it difficult as a beginner to find what I want.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I modified the code to as suggested, but I still get an error.

```js
const observable2 = this.myService.getSecondDataSet();
```

This method requires the firstDataSet to be resolved in order to work. However the console log that `myService.firstDataSet` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (you want to make an API call, wait for it to finish, then depending on the result, send another API request), then you need to use [*switchMap*](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator:

```
return observable1.pipe(
    tap( firstDataSet => this.myService.firstDataSet = firstDataSet),
    switchMap( observable1Result => observable2 ),
    tap(secondDataSet => this.myService.secondDataSet = secondDataSet)            

)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however I still have the same error. Say that the observable2 access `this.myService.FirstDataSet` to make an http call, the console logs an error saying that `this.myService.FirstDataSet` in undefined.

Comment: then maybe there's indeed some problem in your service. Here's an example that I've made, which I hope is similar to your flow: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khgfbs?file=src/app/app.component.ts Have to mention that it's very shortened))