# How to nest api calls in Angular using rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How to nest api calls in angular using rxjs?

```
  getProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
      map((respnose) =>
        respnose.products.map((data) => (item: any) =>
          flatMap(() => this.getProduct(item.id))
        )
      )
    );
  }


// with promises we can do something like promise.all([])... how can I achieve something similar using rxjs
```

But the above method is returning this:

```
[ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
```

& if I do something like this:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
      map((respnose) =>
        respnose.products.map((item: any) => this.getProduct(item.id))
      )
    );
  }
```

it returns:

```
[Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable]
```

Can someone suggest an idea to map the results from one observable to a nested api call (returning observable)?

**NOTE**

`getProduct()` is also an api call returning observable

```
  getProduct(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Observable<any>>(
      `http://localhost:4401/api/products/${id}`,
      {
        params: { id },
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How to go about combining observables depends on the specific use case (do you need data from the first to in order to access the second, do you want to emit both results, etc). Read the documentation for which combiner to use in which use case: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination

Comment: Seems that you have the same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213995/13532354

Answer (score 0):

This is **maybe** what you're looking for. You didn't really tell us what you're trying to do, so it's exceedingly open ended:

This should emit an array of objects (products) with the IDs retrieved from `getProductIDs`

```
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
    map(res => 
      res.products.map(product => this.getProduct(product.id))
    ),
    switchMap(getProducts => forkJoin(getProducts))
  );
}
```

Here's the same thing written a bit more concisely by combining our map into the switchMap:

```
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
    switchMap(res => forkJoin(
      res.products.map(product => this.getProduct(product.id))
    ))
  );
}
```

Here's a way to do it without forkJoin where each Product is emitted one at a time (not in an array)

```
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res.products),
    mergeMap(product => this.getProduct(product.id))
  );
}
```

Here's the same thing, but it emits an array again:

```
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getProductIDs().pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res.products),
    mergeMap(product => this.getProduct(product.id)),
    toArray()
  );
}
```